# Is there any way I could spawn new Spanner nodes based on CPU over utilization?

Tags: database, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

I have a use case where we receive a sudden traffic from API Gateway which results in over utilisation of Spanner node. So someone has to monitor the Spanner node during the peak hours and adjust the nodes as per the cpu utilisation. So I was just wondering is there any way I could just set the threshold in the backend app and spawn the node as per requirement. Let me in case there is any way-out. Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Autoscaling Cloud Spanner nodes based on CPU utilization is not natively supported at the moment, however we are evaluating it for future use. In the meantime, you might want to take a look at the autoscaling library from Spotify which they have made for Bigtable (https://github.com/spotify/bigtable-autoscaler), and modify it to work with Spanner